# RegEx matching multiple exact strings

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I have a string:

```
MPCP-1234 this is test SAF-1234 this is testing
```

I need to match `MPCP-1234` and `SAF-1234`.

My regEx is

```
SAF|MPCP-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

But it is only finding `MPCP-1234` and `SAF` (not `SAF-1234`). I need to match both.

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/oG6yL3/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is the alternative "operator" (`|`). The regex you've posted corresponds to "`SAF`" OR "`MPCP-<4-digit number>`".

What you want is `(?:SAF|MPCP)-\d{4}`. The `\d` matches any digit, and `{4}` means "exactly 4 of the last token" (in this case, `\d`). The `(?:)` means "non-capturing group".

To explain your problem a little better, the alternation character is limited to the current group - if there is no explicit parenthesized group, the entire pattern is used as an implicit group.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, ?: did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SAF|MPCP)-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Group SAF and MPCP. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `"(SAF|MPCP)-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"` may solve your issue, I tested `shell grep ;  echo -e "SAF-1234\nMPCP-1234" | grep -E "(SAF|MPCP)-[0-9]{4}"`